# Unable to figure out how to assert an object correctly

Tags: javascript, object, mutation

```js
let records = {
  2018: {
    Jan: {
      records: [{ 
        id: 123, 
        date: '01-Jan-2018', 
        amount: 300,
        type: 'expense'
       }],
      totalExpenses: 300,
      totalIncome: 0
    },
    Feb: {
      records: [{ 
        id: 234, 
        date: '01-Jan-2019', 
        description: 'Syabas', 
        amount: 100,
        type: 'income'
       }],
      totalExpenses: 0,
      totalIncome: 100
    }
  },
  2019: {
    Jan: {
      records: [{ 
        id: 789, 
        date: '01-Jan-2019', 
        description: 'McD', 
        amount: 150,
        type: 'expense'
       }],
      totalExpenses: 150,
      totalIncome: 0
    },
  }
}
let year = 2018;
let month = 'Jan';

const yearRecords = records[year] || { [year]: {} };
const monthRecords = yearRecords[month] || { [month]: {} };
const recordList = monthRecords['records'] || [];

const newRec = {id: 666, amount: 9999};
const newRecordList = [...recordList, newRec];
monthRecords['records'] = newRecordList;
monthRecords.totalExpenses = newRecordList.reduce((accumulator, record) => {
  return accumulator + record.amount;
}, 0);


console.log({...records, [year]: yearRecords})
```

I have a list of existing `records`, and I'm trying to append new record `newRec` into this `records`.

The challenge is, key of year might/might not exist, same goes to months. If it existed, append into `records` array and increase the `totalExpenses` field.

As shown above, I got it working if `year/month` existed in `records` but if I set it `let year = 2020`, it become one level extra in records which is wrong. I've been trying many hours still couldn't figure it out, wondering if there is any easier way to do assertion as above?

Below will be showing wrong result when the year = 2020

```js
let records = {
      2018: {
        Jan: {
          records: [{ 
            id: 123, 
            date: '01-Jan-2018', 
            amount: 300,
            type: 'expense'
           }],
          totalExpenses: 300,
          totalIncome: 0
        },
        Feb: {
          records: [{ 
            id: 234, 
            date: '01-Jan-2019', 
            description: 'Syabas', 
            amount: 100,
            type: 'income'
           }],
          totalExpenses: 0,
          totalIncome: 100
        }
      },
      2019: {
        Jan: {
          records: [{ 
            id: 789, 
            date: '01-Jan-2019', 
            description: 'McD', 
            amount: 150,
            type: 'expense'
           }],
          totalExpenses: 150,
          totalIncome: 0
        },
      }
    }
    let year = 2020;
    let month = 'Jan';

    const yearRecords = records[year] || { [year]: {} };
    const monthRecords = yearRecords[month] || { [month]: {} };
    const recordList = monthRecords['records'] || [];

    const newRec = {id: 666, amount: 9999};
    const newRecordList = [...recordList, newRec];
    monthRecords['records'] = newRecordList;
    monthRecords.totalExpenses = newRecordList.reduce((accumulator, record) => {
      return accumulator + record.amount;
    }, 0);


    console.log({...records, [year]: yearRecords})
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior (e.g. what should the result actually look like)?

Comment: @naeramarth7: I've added a new section of code with `year=2020` to show my implementation has something wrong. In year `2020` should be showing months but it's showing another `2020` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `reduce` method.

```js
let records = {"2018":{"Jan":{"records":[{"id":123,"date":"01-Jan-2018","amount":300,"type":"expense"}],"totalExpenses":300,"totalIncome":0},"Feb":{"records":[{"id":234,"date":"01-Jan-2019","description":"Syabas","amount":100,"type":"income"}],"totalExpenses":0,"totalIncome":100}},"2019":{"Jan":{"records":[{"id":789,"date":"01-Jan-2019","description":"McD","amount":150,"type":"expense"}],"totalExpenses":150,"totalIncome":0}}}

let month = 'Jan';

function update(year, month, obj, target) {
  [year, month].reduce(function(r, e, i, a) {
    if(!a[i + 1] && r[e]) {
      r[e].records.push(obj);
      r[e].totalExpenses += obj.amount
    }
    return r[e] = (r[e] || (a[i + 1] ? {} : {
      records: [obj],
      totalExpenses: obj.amount,
      totalIncome: 0
    }))
  }, target)
}

update(2018, month, {id: 4, amount: 9999}, records);
update(2020, month, {id: 5, amount: 9999}, records);

console.log(records)
```

Comment: wow I couldn't possibly write this kind of elegant solution just yet. Let me take some time to understand it. Many thanks!